# Caching linq result using HttpContext

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

I would like to cache LINQ result for minimize hitting to database:

```
var result= _db.Company.Select().ToList();
 HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("actions",
     result,
     null,
     Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
     TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

But I get arguments null exceptions.

Comment: Can you put detailed exception here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code throws compilation error in `_db.Company.Select()`, select method required `func<arg>` expression selector of fields, I can't determine why you have call `select()`.

Please specify field selection like `Select(x=>x.Id)` or just use `_db.Company.ToList()`.